# backward quote in listings

Tags: symbols, bash

I'm typesetting a document with examples of bash code. How do I make the code like

```
`pwd -P`
```

appear with the same kind of quotes? I want the readers of the document to be able to copy and paste the code directly into a terminal. Latex is giving me the opening single quote symbol ‘.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the `literate` key to define literate character replacements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\def\backtick{\char18}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{literate={`}{\backtick}1, escapechar=@}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
  @\backtick@pwd -P@\backtick@
  `pwd -P`
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

The copy/paste result from the PDF file is the same for both lines for me. However, note the small spacing difference. I'm not entirely sure which of these spacings is the correct one, but I'm temped to say it's the one of the second line because the `literate` explicitly tells `listings` to treat the replacement as a single character.

Comment: I had to use ``\def\backtick{\`{}}`` instead of ``\def\backtick{\char18}``because this resulted in a different character. Maybe this depends on the locale? (Mine is German.)

Answer (score 6):

Load the `upquote` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
`pwd -P`
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This also changes the `'` character into an undirected quote, which is probably also desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
`pwd -P`
echo '$PATH'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the `upquote` package. I guess it uses a metafont technique. It looked right, but the text copied from the pdf file had `}` and extra spaces instead of backticks.

Comment: @SU3: Do you have the package [cmap](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap) loaded to ensure proper copy'n'paste of text?

Answer (score 3):

With CarLaTeX's comment I was able to find the solution.

First define `escapechar` within your style definition using the `\lstdefinestyle` command. For example,

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{escapechar=@}
```

Then, use the defined style with the `lstlisting` environment.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
  @\`{}@pwd -P@\`{}@
\end{lstlisting}
```

The combination of characters between `@`s will turn into a backtick.

**Edit**:

The solution above looks right on the paper but the characters aren't right when copied from the document. A solution that allows copying is to define a backtick character

```
\def\backtick{\char18}
```

and use it like this

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
  @\backtick@pwd -P@\backtick@
\end{lstlisting}
```