# How to format the text line?

Tags: formatting, text-manipulation

I am using the listings package. In the output line I have a long line with quotes (') and space (_). One can see the two problem:

1. The line is out the margin.
2. The line does not include the quites and spaces.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, caption=Regression model and diagnostic plots]
    
    # Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**Question.** How to format the line in order to fix the problems with the rigth margin and output the quites and spaces on the file.

Comment: Try the option `breaklines=true`

Comment: For the first issue see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116534/lstlisting-line-wrapping

Comment: Second issue for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341004/backward-quote-in-listings

Comment: @Marijn, the 1st problem is solved, but 2nd not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second issue is caused by the characters `‘` and `’`, which are actually not backticks as assumed in a comment but left and right single quotation marks. In LaTeX these are normally represented by the actual backtick `` ` `` (left) and single quote `'` (right). The quotation marks in the source can be mapped to the LaTeX equivalents with `literate`, similar to the linked question.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=R,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
    deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
    breaklines=true,
    literate={‘}{`}1{’}{'}1
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=R, caption=Regression model and diagnostic plots]
    
    # Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]